# xpath for typing in a url for insertting a url

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath

xpaths to me are so bewildering I just haven't got a clue when to use following sibling, ancestors etc.  So I have a text box pop up and my failed attempt of an xpath was //input[text() = Insert URL...'] but to no avail.  Now I know I should insert the code of the elements into this post but I don't know how to copy the elements so here is a screenshot of the code....sorry if you don't like this but this is all I can really do right now for give me.  Please help in me finding an xpath for this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spDkE.png)

I have added the text box which I want the xpath for.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRuHx.png)

Comment: Can you please restructure your question? It's hard to understand what you are looking for, what have you tried, what is the input you want to match against etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do, although I am not familiar with selenium webdriver. Also I've never done xpath on HTML. HTML is not valid XML usually.

`//input[@placeholder='Insert URL...']`

or

`//input[@name='url']`

or

`//input[@placeholder='Insert URL...' and @name='url']`

Comment: Does it make a difference if its a pop up textbox?

Comment: Still doesn't work, for //input[@placeholder='Insert URL...'] there are 2 elements in the code

Comment: Added an extra option to narrow it down maybe. Otherwise you will have to find out what distincts this element from the other element that contains the 'Insert URL...' placeholder.

Comment: Well, 'still doesn't work' does not get us very far. If you look at the HTML, you'll find TWO input elements containing the same 'name' and 'placeholder' attributes. Is there anything that is unique for the element you are looking for? If not: try `//input[@placeholder='Insert URL...'][1]`. That will get you the first element that matches.

Comment: //input[@placeholder='Insert URL...' and @name='url'] was unique and it placed nicely on the element I wanted

Comment: but now I cannot sendkeys to the textbox?

Comment: For that you'll have to ask another question, describing exactly what you want to do, and why it is not working. Or browse the selenium manual.